# Sharing a connection pool inside a closure

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> tide::Result<()> {
    let mut app = tide::new();

    let pool = MySqlPoolOptions::new()
        .max_connections(500)
        .connect(&"mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1/test").await?;
        

    app.at("/").get(|_req: Request<()>| async move {
        let row: (i64,) = sqlx::query_as("select sleep(FLOOR(RAND()*10)) as s")
                                .fetch_one(&pool).await?;
                                
        Ok(Body::from_json(&row)?)
    });
```

But rust compiler complains that `closure is FnOnce because it moves the variable pool out of its environment`. From my understanding, this is an issue because of the borrow checker:

- by passing `pool` to the closure and using `move` semantics on the closure, I am saying that I want the referenced variables to be moved to the closure

My question is: what is the proper way of using `sqlx` connection pool facilities with this kind of code? This is my first rust program so I don't quite understand the borrow checker yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use app state and store pool there, here is [example](https://github.com/http-rs/tide/blob/main/examples/state.rs) how state can be set and used in request handlers